# Apache VirtualHost not working (subdomain)

Tags: apache, subdomain, virtualhost

I guess it'something easy but googeling wasn't helping me. So I ask you.

I tried almost everything so far. Still no success.

I runned this before. Same Server same configs. (Ubuntu Server 12.04 and Apache 2.4) I have migrated from Apache 2.2 to Apache 2.4 with some strugle.

Here are my configs:

My **httpd.conf**:

```html
NameVirtualHost *
```

My **ports.conf**:

```html
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
 Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
 Listen 443
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

and my sits:

000-donbollipage.conf

```html
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/donbollipage/htdocs/
 ServerAdmin admin@donbolli.ch
 ServerName www.donbolli.ch
 #ServerAlias donbolli.info www.donbolli.info donbolli.ch donbolli.ch donbolli.com www.donbolli.com
 
 <Directory /var/www/donbollipage/htdocs/>
  Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride None
  Require all granted
  Satisfy Any
 </Directory>
 
 <Directory /var/www/donbollipage/htdocs/downloads/>
  Options Indexes
  AllowOverride None
 </Directory>

 ErrorLog /var/www/donbollipage/logs/error.log

 # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
 # alert, emerg.
 LogLevel warn

 CustomLog /var/www/donbollipage/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and admin.conf

```html
<VirtualHost *:80>
 DocumentRoot /var/www/admin/htdocs/
 ServerAdmin admin@donbolli.ch
 ServerName admin.donbolli.ch
 
 <Directory /var/www/admin/htdocs/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride None
  Require all granted
  Satisfy Any
 </Directory>

 ErrorLog /var/www/admin/logs/error.log

 LogLevel warn

 CustomLog /var/www/admin/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Somehow when I restart my apache I get a Warning saying I have two sites under Port 80.

```html
[Wed Sep 07 10:40:22 2016] [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 80, the first has precedence
```

Even though I have different ServerName configured.

**Edit:**

All requests go to the default Page. (000-donbollipage)

I used a2ensite to enable the sites. I had several subdomains before.

If I have more than one site active it will switch to whatever is the default.

Comment: You do have two sites listening on port 80.  All the warning means is that if someone goes to the server by IP address rather than domain name they will see the first one.

Comment: When I Connect using Admin.donbolli.ch I still get The other page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those coming fron google, I've managed to get it working. The trick was to add " to DocumentRoot.

Comment: logged in just to upvote and thank you 8 years later